# Swedish language on the facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

The facebook like button javascript looks like this :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=270668283140507&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

By changing the en_US to sv_SE the language should be changed on the buttons but they dont? Its still english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pj5177go/)

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) You need to add this file

```
//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js
```

This one works without that part

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=sv_SE&app_id=185800681493185&amp;href=http://www.yoursite.com&amp;send=false
&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;
action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;
overflow:hidden;width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency=
"true"></iframe>
```

Comment: hmm I dont get this, i look at your FIDDLE example, the top one with the script and it looks exacly like mine becides the DATA URL, yet your buttons is shown in Swedish while mine is not?

Comment: I added the js on the left in the fiddle. If you look at the source of http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pj5177go/show you will see the additional js